# How to delete column from Entity rectangle in Draw.Io entity relationship diagram?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I drew an entity with several fields, then needed to delete some of them. Unfortunately, pressing `Delete` just cleaned field names, but not deleted their rectangles

[image]

How to delete these empty rectangles?

Answer (score 0):

Just double click the row until you select it whole as shown in the image below. Then press Delete or right mouse click > Delete

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Double click on the red arrow showing = sign. You will select the row then will be able to delete.

[image]